A drama movie about children and a possible mother figure struggling for survival in a tent or shack in a desert/plain
Main setting:
A group of young children, possibly with their mother, living in a tent or shack in a desert or a yellow plain surrounded by wheat fields. It was a scorching, treeless, yellow plain. I believe the movie focused on the lifestyle of these people and their struggle for survival. The children might have been neglected or mistreated.
Memorable scene: A steam train passes in the distance from time to time and children are watching it 
Estimated release time: At least 30-35 years ago 
Genre: Drama 
Country of origin: Possibly India or an Arabic/Middle Eastern country (not certain)
There was a general sense of drama and waiting. I’m not sure what the passing train symbolized. For some reason, I remember the setting being somewhere like Arabia or India. They weren’t African, but they had dark skin. I don’t recall a father figure, and I’m not certain if the woman was the children’s mother.
